# negative factorial in summand

Tags: summation, factorial

I've been working on solving some problem and reached to the following equation: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \big[\frac{X^k}{k!} + \frac{kX^{k-1}}{k!} \big] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \big[\frac{X^k}{k!} + \frac{X^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \big]$ ($X$ is a complex matrix, but not too important for the purpose of this equation).

I am wondering whether the second term starts from $k = 1$ since for $k = 0$ we have $-1!$ in the denominator, but I am not entirely sure if this is right. If my guess is wrong, then I'd like to know how the second term at $k=0$ should be calculated.

Comment: If you consider the Gamma function, then this is still the only reasonable convention and it indeed often make work a lot of formulas

Answer (score 1):

In this simplification, you cancelled out a $k$ in the numerator with one in the denominator. But when $k = 0$, there is no $k$ in the denominator. $0! = 1$ by definition. It is not $0$ times anything. Thus you did a nonsense operation and got a nonsense result. The calculation you needed is
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\frac{X^k}{k!} + \frac{kX^{k-1}}{k!} \right] 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{kX^{k-1}}{k!} \\
&= e^X + \left(0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kX^{k-1}}{k!}\right)\\
&= e^X + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{X^{k-1}}{k-1!}\\
&= e^X + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{X^n}{n!}\\
&= 2e^X\end{align}$$

Now, one could object to saying that $\frac{0X^{-1}}{0!} = 0$, since it quite possible that $X^{-1}$ is not even defined, but if so, then the problem already exists in the original expression. And almost certainly, however you obtained that expression, the term should be interpreted as $0$ even if $X^{-1}$ does not exist. But without knowing that derivation, I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{(-1)!}:=0,$ so you get $2e^X$

Comment: No, as Sassatelli Giulio has already pointed out, there is no such convention. Relying on made up expressions like that is going to occasionally lead you to bad results.

Comment: As long as you know what you are doing, you can still choose to use it. But the answer would need some more explanation

Comment: @LL3.14 - as long as you **know** what you are doing, sure. But as long at you *think* you know what you are doing, the ill-arithmetic behavior of $\infty$ is highly likely to occasionally trip you up. Better to not be sure that you know what you are doing, and to check the real mathematics to see what is actually going on.

Comment: I don't think $(-1)!=\infty$ is going to lead us to bad results any more than using e.g. $0!=1$ or $0^0=1$ is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair There is *never* a formal power-series context in which $\frac{1}{(-1)!}\neq 0.$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: @AlexanderConrad - There are several problems with that. (1) it is trivial to come up with formal power series in which treating $\frac{1}{(-1)!} = 0$ causes issues, for example $\sum_{n=0} \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-1)!}x^n$. (2) *formal* means that you are doing symbol manipulation, not paying attention to the meaning. So you can choose to interpret things in the way you want. The OP appears to be concerned about the meaning of the series.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad - (3) When you have young children in your kitchen, you do not lay out all the knifes and explain how useful they are. Instead you tell them "do not touch" until they have developed the motor control and discretion to handle them properly. These "formal" interpretations are not necessary to perform the mathematics, being shortcuts and notational conveniences. And they can be easily misconstrued by neophytes who lack the experience base to handle them properly.

Comment: And if you do not see why this is a problem, please note that in getting to this place the OP interpreted $0! = 0\cdot(-1)!$ and $\frac 00 = 1$. There is a reason $\frac 00$ and $0\cdot \infty$ are called "indeterminant forms".

Comment: @PaulSinclair (1A) Sure, but I see it differently. Differentiate $e^x$ and see if you can justify whether $De^x=e^x.$ The issue isn't in the actual terms we're differentiating, it's in the way we attempt to *encode it* **generally**. Just like in your very clever example, $\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-1)!}x^n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair (2A) The reason it is "undefined" at $k=1$ is not because a $0/0$ occurs, per se, but because we haven't made an explicit choice as to what $f(1)$ *should be*. Another way to say this is that $n!$ represents a *process* moreso than a *number*, to the extent that we obtain a number at the end of the *process*. This manifests at the end of the procedure as an indeterminate form because we have relied on a process and not an ***explicit expression***. For example, there is no issue with differentiating $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots,$ or with $F_k(x,a)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(n+a)^{[k}x^n.$

Comment: @PaulSinclair (3A) $n^{[k}$ is the *falling* or *rising power* function. Take your pick, but the falling power function is equivalent to your original example after shifting $k$. Choose $a$ appropriately.

Comment: @PaulSinclair (1B) I like $n^{\langle k}$ as notation for the falling powers now. Originally I didn't have space, so I put $n^{[k}$ instead of $n^{[k]}$ instead of $n^{\underline{k}}$. Anyway, just a comment.

Comment: That was just a quick example showing that. contrary to your claim of "never", there are formal power series where $1/(-1)! = 0$ is an issue. It is obvious how that particular counter-example can be avoided, but that was not the point. I could have gotten $\infty$ into the numerator in countless other ways, for example, by a rational polynomial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair (a) About rational functions: that's a whole *different* story regardless, **and** we're talking about "$\infty$ in the *denominator*" (though not really: we're actually talking about specificity). If you have examples, I challenge you to cough some up; I think you have overgeneralized our conversation which is about something that is nearly notational, (namely that $1/(-N)!:=0$ is valid) though also a justification of doing these operations.

Comment: @PaulSinclair (b) Can you define what you mean by "know what you're doing", just so I have an idea of your criterion?

Comment: That phrase was LL 3.14's and I was just responding to it. I have already said what my argument is, and pointed out why countering a specific example doesn't change it. If you don't agree, that's fine. We can both go our own way. But this has gone on too long already.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Apologies for the confusion good Sir.